# How to do SUMPRODUCT with percentage and blank cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, percentage, sumproduct

I am trying to do `SUMPRODUCT` in Google Sheets but in a more complicated situation.

I want to sum product with percentage instead of decimal number.

This is what I am doing now, and **it works** just fine:

```
A       B       C       D

        Price   Tax     Cashback
        100     1.09    0.95
        80      1       1
        50      1.09    0.95
Total   =SUMPRODUCT(B:B, C:C, D:D)
```

**What I actually want to do is**

```
A       B       C       D

        Price   Tax     Cashback
        100     9%      5%
        80      
        50      9%      5%
Total   ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B, 1+C2:C, 1-D2:D)
```

[image]